# Mobile device testing for BlackBerry smart phones - acquiring test phones

Tags: blackberry

I have been developing a BlackBerry application for about 7 months, and I have started to do a lot of testing.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to test my application on different BlackBerry devices (without having to purchase them)? I have the BlackBerry Tour and the BlackBerry Storm, but I can only have my Verizon network on one at a time.

Is there a specific way that mobile developers go through this type of testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you join the BlackBerry Alliance program, they have various [Smartphone programs](https://partners.blackberry.com/web/guest/smartphone-programs) to get devices for development and testing.

Answer (score 2):

try this [deviceanywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/)

they are providing remote access for variety of blackberry devices.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the simulators that come with the JDE are true to the real thing.

Comment: I have discovered that to be the case, I just would have a little more piece of mind if I could test it on the actual devices. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can try www.perfectomobile.com. They charge an hourly rate, but you can get 7 free hours.